# Visual Studio Click Once Installer- HTML link not working

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2015, clickonce

I have been learning about VS ClickOnce and have been very impressed.
I have built a test app and have been attempting to learn/test ClickOnce.
I added the link to where I published the setup.exe file but for some reason it is not working.
The setup.exe file and such is on my FTP/website.

What am I missing here? My html code is very simple and should be correct as well.

```
<a href="http://www.overworldinnovations.com/MyApp/setup.exe" download></a>
```

Here are a few screenshots to show my file location and error messages.

Thanks for any/all help on this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close the tag off with

```
</a>
```

Your code should look like this :

```
<a href="http://www.overworldinnovations.com/MyApp/setup.exe"></a>
```

Comment: You were right and that was one issue. Thank you. It still, however, says "Failed- No file" and yet it is on my FTP/website server

Comment: I think that is a chrome issue, I would recommend searching google for a bit and if you don't find anything then create another question. Also, mark my answer as the right one so this problem will be marked as "solved".